# How to remove character from fixed String

Tags: javascript

I have a value like

`V = "Val1,Val2;Val3"`

In this case If I need to separate "Val1,Val2" from V I am using this

`var newVal = V.substr(0, V.indexOf(";"));`

But this case is faling for some value like this

`V = "Val4;Val1,Val2;Val3"`

Any idea how  to take only the value which having "," and remove all other character which is separated by ";"

Comment: use `regex` for this

Comment: What exactly *is* the logic? Anything that matches the [regex](http://regular-expressions.info) `\w+,\w+`…? (hint hint)

Comment: let me try this with regex

Comment: What is this "value"? What is it supposed to represent? Why do you deal with multidimensional data in a string seperated by `;` and `,`? Or are you trying to parse it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the regex

```
\w+,\w+
```

to solve this

```js
function match(str){
    return str.match(/\w+,\w+/g);
}

console.log(match('a;b,c;d'));
console.log(match('a,b;c'));
```

Comment: This is working for small values but if not long values. I am trying this. `"bayern munich germany;wayne rooney, manchester united; messi plays barcelona"`

Comment: what is your expected output? this has to do with the spaces in between the words

Comment: Ya In this case my output should be `wayne rooney, manchester united`

Answer (score 1):

Use `\w+(?=,)` regex to get all those values

Comment: you mean `var  newVal  = V.match(\w+(?=,))

Comment: V.match(/\w+(?=,)/g)